# How to modify the datatype of `id` column for table create using SQLObject

Tags: python, mysql, sqlobject

I am trying to create a table using SQLObject with the following schema

```
class PersonThree(SQLObject):
    firstname = StringCol(length=50)
    lastname = StringCol(length=50)
    age = IntCol()
```

This by default creates the table with `id` column whose datatype in `int`.
I want this table to have the datatype of `id` column to be `bigint`.

I have tried th following

```
class PersonThree(SQLObject):
    class sqlmeta:
        idType = 'bigint'
    firstname = StringCol(length=50)
    lastname = StringCol(length=50)
    age = IntCol()
```

but the above doesn't work.

Is there a way to modify the above schema such that the `id` column has `bigint` datatype.

DB - mysql

Comment: I just released 3.10.3 and added this to my TODO as a feature request.

Comment: Implemented in commit [a0459c0](https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject/commit/a0459c0f93bdd0bda61a172ed8e717e2a239b7d2), will be in the next release, 3.11. Set `sqlmeta.idSize = 'BIG'` and you're done!

Comment: I released the 1st beta: [SQLObject 3.11.0b1](https://pypi.org/project/SQLObject/3.11.0b1/).

Comment: I released [SQLObject 3.11 final](https://pypi.org/project/SQLObject/3.11.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you cannot do that with SQLObject. First, `idType` must be [a callable](https://sqlobject.org/SQLObject.html#class-sqlmeta) that converts Python values to SQL. In short, it must be either `int` or `str`.

Second, `MySQLConnection` [explicitly checks](https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject/blob/e151c186e647aa111254eecbd900462933733984/sqlobject/mysql/mysqlconnection.py#L361-L364) `idType` to be `str` or `int` and creates either `TEXT` or `INT` columns.

The only way currently to do what you want is to create the table outside of SQLObject or alter the table after creation:

```py
class PersonThree(SQLObject):
    class sqlmeta:
        idType = int
PersonThree.createTable()
```

and then

```sql
ALTER TABLE person_three MODIFY COLUMN id BIGINT;
```

You can try a dirty hack: get SQL from `PersonThree.createTableSQL()` instead of `PersonThree.createTable()`, modify it at runtime and execute.

PS. I'm the current maintainer of SQLObject. A working pull request with a test will be accepted.